# When I deploy my app to vercel i resolve an error 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

My App works in the localhost very well, but when I deploy it , it gives me an error

[image]

In View Function logs, it gives me this error

> ERROR

```
    Error: Cannot find module '/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/next.js'. Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
    at tryPackage (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:321:19)
    at Function.Module._findPath (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:534:18)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:888:27)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:93:18)
    at Object.284 (/var/task/.next/server/pages/login.js:23:39)
    at __webpack_require__ (/var/task/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:25:42)
    at __webpack_exec__ (/var/task/.next/server/pages/login.js:89:39)
    at /var/task/.next/server/pages/login.js:90:28 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  path: '/var/task/node_modules/next/package.json',
  requestPath: 'next',
  page: '/login'
}
RequestId: 2ae473a5-56ed-4fc5-89d5-2b2777324841 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
> Blockquote
```

Comment: Do you have a pages/api/subscribe.js file in app?

Comment: No !! , What's that file

Comment: Like how you import your Next API routes similar to this, import next from "next" or import { NextApiRequest, NextApiResponse } from 'next'

Comment: I don't understand , but it work in localhost without this

Comment: Yea that's fine so how do you manage your routes for your app?

Comment: pages > api > auth > [...nextauth].js

Comment: pages > _app.js + index.js + login.js

Comment: Do you have any Next routes imports on login.js or index.js

Comment: No !! I have not

Comment: No !! I have not

Comment: Can you share the contents of “/pages/login.js”?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the first line of the log:

```
Please verify that the package.json has a valid "main" entry
```

Can you please share your package.json?